# populate Html table with remote files

Tags: html, linux, remote-access

I want to create a HTML page that will have a table that will populate itself with info from 2 .txt files that are on a remote Linux Server.
or populate a html page on that remote server with the same info from those 2 .txt files and then access that html page using apache's webserver.

something as basic as possible would be nice but I can understand if it's complicated to do with html

honestly, any help at all would be nice.

Comment: I would say you just need a PHP file that would read your text file and outputs the content to a table.  How is the text file formatted and what is the end result?

Comment: HTML can't do anything, HTML is a visual format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally do it in `PHP`.  You can read the file and `echo` it into a table.  You can then use the lines of the file for anything you want.  I put comments in explaining each step.  All you have to do is change `$filepath` to point at your text file:

**Edited**: Edited the code to add constraints mentioned by OG poster in comments.  There is probably a more optimized way of performing your task, but this works and should introduce some new concepts to you if you are new to PHP

```
<?php
    $filepath = 'files/the_file.txt';
    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        $file = fopen($filepath, 'r');
        echo '<table border=1>';
        while (!feof($file)) {
            $line = fgets($file);
            $first_char = $line[0];
            if ($first_char != '*' && $first_char != '^' && trim($line) != '') {
                if (strstr($line, '|')) {
                    $split = explode('|', $line);
                    echo '<tr>';
                    foreach($split as $line) {
                        echo '<td>'.$line.'</td>';
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                } else {
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$line.'</td></tr>';
                }
            }
        }
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo 'the file does not exist';
    }
?>
```

I'll do my best to explain it line by line instead of flooding the scrip with comments:

1. set your file path
2. If the file exists, continue on.  If not, throw the error located at the bottom of the script
3. open the file
4. create the table ('`<table>`')
5. while the text file is being read, do a series of things:  First, get the line.  If the first character of the line is a * or ^, or when the line is trimmed there are no characters, skip it completely. Otherwise, continue on
6. if the line contains a | character, split (`explode`) the line at all of the | characters.  Use this array of split up content and for each piece of content, `echo` out a new column in the existing row with the current content.  Otherwise, there is not | found and you can just echo the line into a row normally
7. once you are finished up, end the table ('`</table>`')

**Edit #2:** The original solution I posted:

```
<?php
    $filepath = '/var/www/files/the_file.txt';
    if (file_exists($filepath)) {
        $file = fopen($filepath, 'r');
        echo '<table border=1>';
        while (!feof($file)) {
            $line = fgets($file);
            echo '<tr><td>'.$line.'</td></tr>';
        }
        echo '</table>';
    } else {
        echo 'the file does not exist';
    }
?>
```

Comment: this works almost perfectly, is there a way to have it ignore lines that start with * or ^ and have it split the line when it finds a | ?

Comment: @FateAverie When you say "Split the line", do you intent to put everything after the "|" on another line or in another tab cell (row)?

Comment: another cell in the same row, but I also have an issue with the blank lines are being added in as well, is there a way to get rid of the line is it's blank or has only spaces/indents

Comment: @FateAverie My original answer has been edited to include the things you need.  Let me know if there is anything you do not understand. Please accept this answer if it works for you!

Comment: @FateAverie Weird, I tested it and it worked fine for me.  Right-click the page and view the source.  See what the last thing printed is.  If you are least getting a blank page it is probably a parsing error, not a syntax error.

Comment: I figured out it was because I put '$trim' instead of 'trim' it was my mistake, I ran it again with ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); to find the error and thats how I figured out I messed up, my bad

Comment: @FateAverie Great! Glad you got it working. Please accept this answer if is solves your problem!  Let me know if you need any clarification..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18817/discussion-between-fate-averie-and-burmat)

Answer (score 0):

HTML can't do anything, HTML is a presentation format.

PHP, Javascript, BASH could do the job in very different ways :

- PHP : the server calls the 2 remote files and output the assembled html file into a webpage, then send it to the client
- Javascript : the page itself calls the 2 files and add them in itself.
- Bash + CURL : a BASH (or PHP, Python...) script creates a .html file containing the data of the 2 files.

Comment: makes sense, i wasn't expecting to write code out in html I was just looking for something that could run in it, but I figure I'll use PHP instead

Answer (score 0):

One of these might help you, if you can precreate the HTML rather than doing it dynamically.  These scripts take CSV as input and output an HTML table:

[http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/to-table/](http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/to-table2/)

http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/svn/to-table2/

Comment: I have a precreated the HTML table template and I need to display the entire table (with fix rows and columns) even with empty cells when it is partially filled. I have tried to use placeholders in each cell in the HTML file and replace the placeholders with actual data (find and replace) from the file. This seems to me as not an optimal approach. Requesting suggestion.